# Enforce Eq check on trait

Tags: rust

Suppose the following objects:

```
pub struct MyStruct<T>{
  items: Vec<T>
}

pub impl<T> MyStruct<T> {
  pub fn new() -> MyStruct {
     MyStruct{ items::new(); }
  }
  pub fn add(&mut self, item: T) where T : Eq {
    self.items.push(item);
  }
}

pub trait C {}

pub struct Another {
  mystruct: MyStruct<Box<C>>
}

pub impl Another {
  pub fn exec<C>(&mut self, c: C) where C: Eq + C {
     self.mystruct.add(c);
  }
}
```

On exec I'm enforcing that C also is Eq, but I'm receiving the following error:

```
 error: the trait `core::cmp::Eq` is not implemented for the type `C`
```

I had to make

```
pub impl<T> MyStruct<T>
```

instead of

```
pub impl<T : Eq> MyStruct<T>
```

because since C is a trait I cant enforce Eq when using MyStruct::new, so I left the check for the type guard on the function. What's happening here?

Comment: Your example code doesn't reproduce the error you claim it does (it's not an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). You may get more responses if it did. Additionally, the Rust style is 4-space indents.

Comment: Since Chris Morgan has the answer covered, I'll also point out that your implementation of `add` has a type parameter `T` that shadows the type parameter of the struct, and in your implementation of `exec`, the type parameter `C` shadows the trait `C`, which leads to a potentially confusing error message.

Comment: @Shepmaster, thanks for the feedback. In fact add didn't had a template, it was caused by a copy/paste error and class renaming (compiling this causes an error about shadowing just like you mentioned). Next time I'll try to create a MCVE to better reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let’s look at the relevant definitions for `Eq`:

```
pub trait Eq: PartialEq<Self> {
    …
}

pub trait PartialEq<Rhs: ?Sized = Self> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Rhs) -> bool;
    …
}
```

Now consider `MyStruct<Box<C>>`: the type that it wants to implement `Eq` is `Box<C>`, a boxed trait object. To implement `Eq`, `Box<C>` must first implement `PartialEq<Box<C>>`, like this:

```
impl PartialEq for Box<C> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Box<C>) -> bool;
}

impl Eq for Box<C> { }
```

That is, you must be able to compare an arbitrary `Box<C>` with any other arbitrary `Box<C>`. The boxed trait objects that you are comparing could be of different concrete types, here. Thus you need to write this implementation manually. In such cases, you will typically want the trait to include some way of normalising the form of the object into a concrete, comparable type; for some types this is obvious; if `AsRef<T>` was to have a `PartialEq` implementation added, the implementation to add would be fairly obvious:

```
impl<T: PartialEq> PartialEq for AsRef<T> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &AsRef<T>) -> bool {
        self.as_ref() == other.as_ref()
    }
}
```

(Note also that if `C` implements `PartialEq`, `Box<C>` does, so such implementations as we’re discussing should go on the unboxed trait object, not on the boxed trait object.)

Quite often, however, there is *not* an obvious and simple implementation. There are a few approaches you could take:

1. Convert the objects (potentially expensively, though ideally cheaply) into some base type, e.g. a `String` which can then be compared;
2. Give up;
3. Constrain `C` to `'static` types and use some fancy `Any` magic to make it so that it uses the base type’s `PartialEq` implementation, returning `false` if the two trait objects are not of the same concrete type. This one is a fairly useful one, so I’ll give some code for it:

   ```rust
   #![feature(core)]

   use std::any::{Any, TypeId};
   use std::mem;

   fn main() { }

   trait PartialEqFromC {
       fn eq_c(&self, other: &C) -> bool;
   }

   impl<T: PartialEq + Any + C> PartialEqFromC for T {
       fn eq_c(&self, other: &C) -> bool {
           if other.get_type_id() == TypeId::of::<Self>() {
               self == unsafe { *mem::transmute::<&&C, &&Self>(&other) }
           } else {
               false
           }
       }
   }

   trait C: Any + PartialEqFromC {
   }

   impl PartialEq for C {
       fn eq(&self, other: &C) -> bool {
           self.eq_c(other)
       }
   }
   ```

   Note that this example depends on the unstable feature `core` for `Any.get_type_id` and is thus tied to nightly only; this can be worked around by duplicating that definition from the `Any` trait into a new supertrait of `C` and could also be simplified by [mopafying the `C` trait](https://github.com/chris-morgan/mopa).

Comment: I wish I could award an extra vote for option 2. ^_^

Comment: fantastic reply! thank you for this detailed explanation and for the link for your lib, that gives food for thought. One question, this kind of usage is idiomatic rust? My main idea here was to create a Bag collection where T would be identifiable (through Eq).

Comment: Using trait objects is not particularly common, and exposing `Any` or things like it is not typically idiomatic. It can, however, be used very legitimately internally. AnyMap, for example, uses `Any` internally, but (unless you dive into the raw interface which is also now exposed for certain obscure situations) exposes an interface entirely devoid of `Any` trait objects.